# CoreOS and NTFS

Tags: ntfs, coreos

Is there a way I can mount an NTFS filesystem on CoreOS?

I can't install ntfs-3g on CoreOS itself.
I can create a docker image that has ntfs-3g installed and I can mount my NTFS drive within a docker container.
However, I can't seem to find a way to make the mounted filesystem available anywhere other than in the container that mounted it.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?!

Comment: I have data on an NTFS filesystem that I want to be able to access from my docker apps.  The exact reason it is locked on NTFS is long and boring.  The short answer is "because legacy."

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that I am mounting with fuse.  As per the below thread, it doesn't look like it is possible to get a fuse mount point out of a container:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-dev/_8bAG561VAI

I solved my problem by creating an NFS share within the mounting container and using that.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the container with the --privileged flag and bind mount it back to the host it can be made available to other containers:

First spawn the container as follows:

`$ docker run --privileged -v /mnt:/data NTFSContainer`

Then mount the device into `/data` inside the container

Now the files will be exposed to the underlying host and can be shared into other containers as well.

Comment: I've tried that.  The mounted filesystem appears within the container, but on the host it is still an empty directory.  I've tried to include /sys and /proc as volumes as well, no joy.

Comment: This might work with non-fuse mounts, though I think doing this with a non-fuse mount would be a pretty odd case.

Comment: Here is a video I did of a POC using the Gluster FUSE tools - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjM0YqCkIz8&list=UUIG9tBpNZxYgNtWBYP1vCIA

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it looks like you are mounting a FUSE filesystem within a container, and then accessing that mount point from within the same container.

I want to be able to then export that mount point to be used by other containers (with say --volumes-from), or from the host.

I can access the mounted volume within the same container just fine, but it shows up as just an empty directory when I try to get access to it somewhere else.